# StoredProcedures.cs empty

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic

When I generate the DAL via SubCommander/sonic.exe I get an empty StoredProcedures.cs
All that's in it is:`using System; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using SubSonic; 
using SubSonic.Utilities;`

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

I'm using SubSonic 2.1, all other classes are generated properly.

Edit:
I tried: GRANT ALL ON PROCEDURE testDb.testStoredProc TO 'testUser'@'%'; 
But it doesn't appear even if the user has all privilegies to the stored proc.

Edit 2:
I am using MySQL 5 database

Comment: Please edit your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have includeProcedureList or excludeProcedureList defined in your config options. I would guess you've got something like excludeProcedureList="*" or includeProcedureList=""

Comment: I have neither in my config. But I tried adding  spClassName="SPs" useSPs="True" includeProcedureList="*" excludeProcedureList="" to the provider, and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error with the Oracle Provider.  What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.0.24a-community-max-nt on server.. and SubSonic is built against MySql.Data.dll 5.2.5.

Comment: I have the exact same issues, I'm using Oracle 10g. What should I do?